# NIO Selector Thread, handling channels as expected, but how do I ensure channels are correctly closed after use?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, nio

So I have the following code in my ServerRunnable class:

```
public class FirmwareServerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FirmwareServerRunnable.class
            .getName());
    private LinkedTransferQueue<CommunicationState> communicationQueue;
    private int serverPort = 48485;

    public FirmwareServerRunnable(int port,
            LinkedTransferQueue<CommunicationState> communicationQueue) {
        serverPort = port;
        this.communicationQueue = communicationQueue;
    }

    private boolean running;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort));

            log.info("Selector Thread: FirmwareServer Runnable- Listening for connections on port: "
                    + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

            running = true;

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            SelectionKey serverAcceptKey = serverSocketChannel.register(
                    selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

            while (running) {

                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

                while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keyIterator.next();

                    if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

                        acceptConnection(selector, key);
                        keyIterator.remove();

                    } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {
                        CommunicationState commsState = (CommunicationState) key
                                .attachment();
                        if (commsState.getCurrentState() == CommunicationState.STATE_READ) {
                            readFromSocketChannel(key);
                            keyIterator.remove();
                        }
                    } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) == SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) {

                        CommunicationState commsState = (CommunicationState) key
                                .attachment();
                        if (commsState.getCurrentState() == CommunicationState.STATE_WRITE) {


                            writeToSocketChannel(key);
                            keyIterator.remove();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(
                    "Firmware Selector Thread: An IOException occurred",
                    e);     
        }

    }
```

My `acceptConnection()` method accepts a connection and adds a `CommunicationState` Object (a state machine) to it that contains things like a `ByteBuffer`, current channel state, where the client currently is in the communication process etc...
This server switches between communication methods mid process. Initially it uses JSON messages to communicate with the client, but when it gets to a certain point it starts to flash the client with new firmware using [USART protocol commands](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00264342.pdf).

Once the process is completed, the client disconnects and reboots. This leaves my channel in an unknown state. I am unsure if the channel has been closed or not on my side. 
How can I check this? Am I correct in thinking that `selector.selectedKeys()` only returns keys that are ready for operations? if that's the case, how can I check for connections that haven't been closed properly? Can I do it in this `ServerRunnable`  `while(running){}` loop?

One option I've been considering is attaching a reference to the key itself to the CommunicationState machine, then I can get a reference to the channel once the process is complete and close it there. But I'm uneasy about this solution for some reason, it doesn't feel right to me.

If it's the case that even closed channel keys are included can I use `key.isValid()` to confirm that the key needs to be removed permanently?

I'd appreciate any thoughts you might have on the process, I must be overlooking something.

EDIT: a quick test seems to suggest that channel keys aren't included in the selected keys set unless they are ready for one of the three defined operations
My test was bad.

Comment: Re your edit, of course that's the case. The selected-keys set is the set of keys that got selected for the operations they are registered for.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm grasping at straws here! :-) Back to a methodical approach it is so.

Comment: I'm going to try step through the code again. I have a situation, where the process is completing, the client successfully reboots, but the processor on my machine remains between the 30% - 40% mark, as if it's continuing to loop, which it is as best I can tell. my `readFromSocketChannel()` method doesn't appear to be called. I have logging to output the bytes read, and to say when the channel has been closed, but neither of those are being printed.

Comment: OK, I found the issue, my state machine is in the wrong state, so it doesn't get to call the `readFromSocketChannel()` method. Thank you for your patience, you've been very helpful!

Comment: After some debugging it turns out the state was correct. The bug occurred as a result of me not understanding that the `-1` would be returned in the `byteBuffer` itself, and not in the value returned by `int read = socketChannel.read(byteBuffer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection that has been closed by the peer will cause the selector to treat your channel to it as readable, and when you read from it you will get -1, whereupon you should close the channel, which will cancel its selection key.

**EDIT**

> If it's the case that even closed channel keys are included can I use key.isValid() to confirm that the key needs to be removed permanently?

If you closed the channel, its key got cancelled, so you won't see it in the selected-keys set next time. If the *peer* closed the *connection,* see above.

Comment: OK, thanks, my `readFromSocketChannel()` method handles that. This raises other issues. I obviously have a loop somewhere that's not exiting properly after the client disconnects.